# Unresolved reference: test. when adding module for android tests

Tags: android, module, android-testing

I've started a hello world project in Android Studio.

I've added `test-shared` as a module because the files in there need to be seen by `test` and `androidTest`.

[image]

**settings.gradle:**

```
include ':app'
include ':test-shared'
rootProject.name = "My Application"
```

**build.gradle (app level):**

```
dependencies {
    androidTestImplementation(project(":test-shared"))
    testImplementation(project(":test-shared"))
}
```

**build.gradle (test-shared):**

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.4.2"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.3"
    implementation "junit:junit:$junit"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junit"
}
```

And within `ExampleInstrumentedTest` I try to call a method in `MainCoroutineRule`:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    @Test
    fun useAppContext() {
        MainCoroutineRule().doSomething()
    }
}
```

Which gives the error message:

**Unresolved reference: test**

for the test directory, the same result.

Comment: shot in the dark here... try replacing androidTestImplementation(project(":test-shared")) with androidTestImplementation(project(path: ":test-shared")) . Notice the extra 'path: '

Comment: no, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

change **build.gradle** `test-shared` to:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.4.2"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.3"
    implementation "junit:junit:$junit"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
}
```

and add:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude "META-INF/licenses/**"
    exclude "META-INF/AL2.0"
    exclude "META-INF/LGPL2.1"
}
```

to **build.gradle** App level

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution will be to use a specific folder inside the app module, for example `sharedTest`

then in your `build.gradle.kts` for `app` you could have something like this

```kotlin
android {
        
    sourceSets {
        this.getByName("androidTest") {
            resources.srcDirs("src/androidTest/resources", "src/sharedTest/resources")
        }
        this.getByName("test") {
            resources.srcDirs("src/test/resources", "src/sharedTest/resources")
        }
    }
}
```

This ensures that `test` and `androidTest` will use the `resources` in `testFolder`

Answer (score 0):

Resource for how to set up a shared Test folder.

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEmFifgS0PY

In the app gradle add the following code block, which allows the `androidTest` and `test` source set to access resources within the package, without this section the java folder will remain grey and can't be properly accessed.

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        androidTest.java.srcDirs += "src/test-shared/java"
        test.java.srcDirs += "src/test-shared/java"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add `junit` dependency to your `build.gradle` (app level)

```
dependencies {
    ...
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junit"
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).